# Simplifying an expression by plugging some "knowledge" into it

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, eliminate

I am having trouble simplifying an expression using some characteristics ("knowledge") I have regarding the variables. In the expression below, I have the weighted average `r0=p1 r1+p2 r2`, where the probabilities $p_i$ sum to 1, i.e. `p1=1-p2`. I wish to simplify the expression "as much as possible" using this knowledge. So far, the use of Eliminate has not proven useful because, from what I can tell if it cannot replace all the occurrences of what I am trying to eliminate, then it does nothing. For example, on a simpler expression than the one I am working on, I can successfully do the transformation I want in the first Eliminate, but when I add r2 to the expression, the second Eliminate fails, presumably because it cannot completely eliminate r2... What I would like is a "best effort", such as what I wrote in the second comment:

```
p1 = 1 - p2;
Solve[Eliminate[{expr == (-1 + q + (-1 + p2)  q  r1 - p2  q  r2 + 
      p  (r1 - p2  r1 + p2  r2)) , r0 == p1  r1 + p2  r2}, {r1, 
   r2}], expr] (* works: {{expr->-1+q+p r0-q r0}} *)
Solve[Eliminate[{expr == (-1 + q + (-1 + p2)  q  r1 - p2  q  r2 + 
       p  (r1 - p2  r1 + p2  r2)) + r2 , r0 == p1  r1 + p2  r2}, {r1, 
   r2}], expr] (* does not work, I would like {{expr->-1+q+p r0-q r0+r2}} *)
```

The actual expression I am trying to simplify is the following:

```
exprToSimplify=(1 + q (-1 + r1) - p r1) (1 + q (-1 + r2) - p r2) (-1 + 
   q + (-1 + p2) q r1 - p2 q r2 + 
   p (r1 - p2 r1 + 
      p2 r2)) (((-1 + p) p ((-1 + p2) r1 - 
        p2 r2) (q^4 (-1 + r1)^2 (-1 + r2)^2 ((-1 + p2) r1 - p2 r2) - 
        q^3 (-1 + r1) (-1 + r2) ((-1 + p2) r1 - 
           p2 r2) (2 - (1 + 2 p) r2 + r1 (-1 + p (-2 + 4 r2))) + 
        p q (r1 r2 (-1 + r1 - p2 r1 + p2 r2) + 
           p (p2 (-1 + r2) r2^2 + (-1 + p2) r1^3 (-1 + 3 r2) + 
              r1 r2^2 (1 + 2 p2 - 3 p2 r2) + 
              r1^2 (-1 + p2 + 3 r2 - 2 p2 r2 - r2^2)) - 
           2 p^2 r1 r2 (p2 (-1 + r2) r2 + (-1 + p2) r1^2 (-1 + 2 r2) +
               r1 (-1 + p2 + 2 r2 - 2 p2 r2^2))) + 
        p^3 r1 r2 (p2 (-1 + r2) r2 + (-1 + p2) r1^2 (-1 + p r2) + 
           r1 (-1 + p2 + p (r2 - p2 r2^2))) + 
        q^2 (-p2 (-1 + r2) r2 (-1 + 2 p r2 + p^2 r2) + 
           p (-1 + p2) r1^3 (2 + p - 3 r2 - 6 p r2 + 6 p r2^2) + 
           r1 (-1 + p2 + r2 + 
              3 p r2 - (p2 + p (2 + 4 p2) + p^2 (1 + 5 p2)) r2^2 + 
              3 p (1 + 2 p) p2 r2^3) + 
           r1^2 ((-1 + p2) (-1 + r2) + 
              2 p (1 - p2 + (-3 + 2 p2) r2 + r2^2) - 
              p^2 (-1 + p2 + (6 - 5 p2) r2 - 7 r2^2 + 
                 6 p2 r2^3)))))/((q (-1 + r1) - p r1) (1 + 
        q (-1 + r1) - p r1) (q (-1 + r2) - p r2) (1 + q (-1 + r2) - 
        p r2)) + ((-1 + p)^2 p q ((-1 + p2) r1 - 
        p2 r2) (2 q^2 (-1 + r1) (-1 + r2) ((-1 + p2)^2 r1^2 + 
           p2 r2 (-1 + p2 r2) - (-1 + p2) r1 (-1 + 2 p2 r2)) + 
        2 p^2 r1 r2 ((-1 + p2)^2 r1^2 + 
           p2 r2 (-1 + p2 r2) - (-1 + p2) r1 (-1 + 2 p2 r2)) - 
        p q (2 (-1 + p2)^2 r1^3 (-1 + 2 r2) + 
           p2 r2^2 (1 + p2 - 2 p2 r2) - (-1 + p2) r1^2 (2 - p2 - 
              2 (3 + p2) r2 + 8 p2 r2^2) + 
           2 r1 r2 (1 + p2 - 4 p2 r2 + 
              p2^2 (-1 + r2 + 2 r2^2)))) z)/((q (-1 + r1) - 
        p r1) (q (-1 + r2) - p r2) (q + (-1 + p2) q r1 - p2 q r2 + 
        p (r1 - p2 r1 + p2 r2))));
```

So far, I have been writing a set of rules which I find manually by looking at the expression and simplifying what I can by hand, e.g.:

```
repl={(-1 + p2)  r1 - p2  r2 -> -r0, 
   r1 - p2  r1 + p2  r2 -> r0, (-1 + p2)  q  r1 - p2  q  r2 -> -q  r0,
    q - q  r0 -> 
    q  (1 - r0), (-1 + p2)^2  r1^2 + 
     p2  r2  (-1 + p2  r2) - (-1 + p2)  r1  (-1 + 2  p2  r2) -> -r0 + 
     r0^2};
Simplify[exprToSimplify/.repl]
```

As you can tell, some of the simplifications are not obvious, and I had a bit of luck finding the one with the squared terms. I will likely not be as lucky trying to simplify any cubic terms...

My question is: given Eliminate appears to do "all or nothing" and that Replace requires me to do all the heavy lifting (and likely omitting some identities along the way), is there a better approach to simplify this expression?

Comment: Have you tried `Simplify` together with appropriate assumptions?

Comment: I think your question lacks an example where your method does not work. It is hard to answer if there is no problem. Generally `Simplify` with assumptions should work, as @MarkoB suggested.

Comment: In general, you can not eliminate 2 variables from 2 equations. This is only possible in special cases like your first example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @MarcoB, I have tried Simplify with the assumption `r0==p1 r1+r2 r2`, but this does not siplify anything more; the Simplify with the replacement rules is all I have been able to achieve using Simplify. @yarchik, the code at the very top illustrates what I am trying to achieve with an example that works and one that does not, using Eliminate; the idea I was trying to give with that example is that simply adding `r2` makes the simplification fail. @Daniel Huber, that confirms the wall I was hitting with Eliminate: do you know of an alternative? Thanks!